# How can I implement this via pure css about :first-of-type

Tags: css

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!--
      Several random elements that I'm not able to predict.
      div, p, h3, etc. 
    --> 
    <div class="foo">...</div>
    <!-- 
      Could have only 1 .foo, 2 .foo, or 3, 4, 5 .foo... 
    -->
    <div class="foo">...</div>
    <!--
      Also several random elements
    -->
</div>
```

HTML code is something like above. Now I know the reason why `div.foo:first-of-type` doesn't work. But is there any alternative solution?

How can I select the first `.foo`? How can I select the last `.foo`? Of course via pure css...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something like- p:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: #ff0000;
}

Comment: first-of-type only applies to element, if you add a class to it, it still needs to be first-of-type to match the class. you will need javascript. CSS has limits ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I select the first `.foo`?

The technique described here: [CSS selector for first element with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class):

```
div.foo {
  /* Style all */
}

div.foo ~ div.foo {
  /* Revert styles for all but the first */
}
```

> How can I select the last `.foo`?

The technique described above relies on sibling selectors and overrides. The biggest limitation of sibling selectors is that they only work in one direction, and since they work for the first element by overriding for all elements *after* the first, they won't work for the last because you can't select siblings that come *before* some other element using sibling selectors.

There is no pure CSS alternative.

Comment: There is an alternative ...  I hope that I don't get many downvotes for posting it ...

Comment: yes I'm stuck at the last `.foo` too. But anyway, the first `.foo` solution is correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Any HTML5 browser will let you use nth-of-type as it is intended...

I am not saying this is a recomended technique, I am just showing how this option works ...

I don't know if you will like it or not, but AFAIK is the only way to get what you want for the last one (as BoltClock says)

```css
foo:first-of-type {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

foo:last-of-type {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>div</div>
  <foo>foo</foo>
  <div>div</div>
  <foo>foo</foo>
  <div>div</div>
  <foo>foo</foo>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah I know this is a workaround but in my case I can't use such customized tag `<foo>`. Thanks anyway~!

Answer (score 0):

you can use first-child, and last-child

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
</div>
```

css

```
p:first-child {
    color: red;
}

p:last-child {
    color: green;
}
```

Here's a [JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Le4d74r6/)

Beware that last-child is only supported since IE 9, and first-child is supported from IE 7

Comment: @BoltClock his question is how to select the first & last of `.foo` ... sorry if I dont get what he meant